# Facing problem in opening android studio emulator

Tags: android, flutter

When i am running my emulator it constantly giving me the error to unable to locate adb files however they are already stored in the sub folder. I also downloaded the files separately and then replaced them but it didn't work too.. please help me with this..

Comment: Attach image and say more details

Comment: Adding image and error message would provide more clarity

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are connected to the internet, run and see what happens